# Is upgrading houses worth it in Little Raiders?

Tags: little-raiders

How long does it take for house upgrades to pay themselves off?

Answer (score 1):

Verdict: upgrading is definitely worth it, as long as you plan to play the game for at least a few more days and collect somewhat regularly.

s=silver

- House lvl 1: 10s/10min

  - Hits capacity in 70 min = 1.17 hours
- House lvl 2: 20s/10min, 1,250s to upgrade.

  - Pays itself off in 1,250 min = 20.83 hours
  - Hits capacity in 200 min = 2.33 hours
- House lvl 3: 30s/10min, 5,000s to upgrade.

  - Pays itself off in 5,000 min = 2.43 days
  - Hits capacity in 250 min = 4.17 hours
- House lvl 4: 50s/10min, 10,000s to upgrade.

  - Pays itself off in 5,000 min = 2.43 days
  - Hits capacity in 350 min = 5.83 hours
- House lvl 5: 60s/10min, 14,000s to upgrade.

  - Pays itself off in 14,000 min = 9.72 days
  - Hits capacity in 417 min = 6.94 hours

Heros' houses

- Hero's house lvl 1: 20s/10min
- Hero's house lvl 2: 40s/10min, 3,250s to upgrade.

  - Pays itself off in 1,625 min = 27 hours
  - Hits capacity in 200 min = 2.33 hours
- Hero's house lvl 3: 60s/10min, 14,000s to upgrade.

  - Pays itself off in 10,000 min = 6.94 days
  - Hits capacity in 250 min = 4.17 hours
- Hero's house lvl 4: 100s/10min, 27,000s to upgrade.

  - Pays itself off in 6,750 min = 4.69 days
  - Hits capacity in 350 min = 5.83 hours

Other advantages of upgrading

- Silver capacity (time before you have to come back and collect)
- Faster healing
- Fame